# Find the expectation of a function that contains absolute value of Gaussian variables?

Tags: random-variables

Given $x \sim \mathcal{N}(x|0;1)$ and $y \sim \mathcal{N}(y|1;1)$,$x,y$ are two independent variables. How to find the expectation
$\int \int (1+|x-y| )e^{-|x-y|}\mathcal{N}(x|0;1)\mathcal{N}(y|1;1) dx dy$.  In other words, how to find the  expecation of $f=(1+|x-y| )e^{-|x-y|}$ when $x,y$ are Gaussian random variables.

The absolute value makes the problem somewhat difficult.

Thank you so much

Comment: Are $x,y$ independent, or do you know something else about their joint distribution?  Do you have any reason to think there should be a nice closed form for this expectation?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. x,y are two independent Gaussian random variables. I already edited my post. I hope that we can compute a closed form of this expectation, so it would be very helpful for my work later.